# Is there a risk in inference of structural variations using mate-pairs?

Tags: structural-variation

Inference of structural variants from short read data is always sneaky (for a question about pair-end reads, see [this](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/120/how-can-i-call-structural-variants-svs-from-pair-end-short-read-resequencing-d)). Recently I bumped into [a paper](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1111/mec.15016) where they used mate-pairs for inference of structural variants and it made me wonder if the approach might be problematic or not.

Mate-pairs have a known problem of [contamination by pair-end reads](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/27153683) and there is even a tool for calling structural variations considering this problem called [SVachara](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5629590/). However, authors have used methods [Lumpy](https://doi.org/10.1093/bioinformatics/btq665) and [Delly2](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3436805/). Have they chosen an appropriate approach?